# Stop Facebook Pixel tracking on localhost and development server

Tags: tracking, facebook-pixel

I'm using Facebook Pixel for tracking on my website.

```
<script>
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
    {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
    n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
    if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
    n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
    t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
    'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
    fbq('init', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    fbq('track', 'PageView');
  </script>
  <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
    src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=320956065128864&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
  /></noscript>
```

Any solution to stop or filter like GA filter excludes domain or IP? Thanks.

Comment: Don’t think they provide an option for that, so you’d have to implement that yourself by not outputting this tracking code as part of your page in the first place, depending on your criteria.

Comment: Thanks, @misorude. This is the last possible solution I think can use when don't have any option from Fb :)

Answer (score 7):

Code snipet for adding FB pixel is first checking if FB pixel is already added, by checking for variable `fbq`:

```
if(f.fbq)return;
```

So the simplest way to skip FB pixel script from initial injection is to define `fbq` variable before FB snipet.

```
<script>
    const list = ['localhost'];
    if (list.includes(window.location.hostname)) {
        window.fbq = function() {};
    }
    // ...original Facebook Pixel code here
</script>
```

Add any domain to the `list` array in order to block FB pixel execution.

Answer (score 4):

In Traffic permissions, you can allow only the production domain, which will automatically block localhost.
[image: FB Traffic permissions setup]

Details here:
https://www.facebook.com/business/help/278125336598935?id=1205376682832142